# Receiving Multipart Response on client side (ClosableHttpResponse)

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, multipart

I have a java controller which have to send me some text data and different byte arrays. So I am building n multipart request and writing it to stream from HttpServletResponse.

Now my problem is how to parse the response at client side and extract the multiple parts.

SERVER CODE SNIPPET:-

```
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        // Prepare payload
        builder.addBinaryBody("document1", file);
        builder.addBinaryBody("document2", file2);
        builder.addPart("stringData", new StringBody(jsonData, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));

        // Set to request body

        HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
        postRequest.setEntity(entity);
```

CLIENT CODE SNIPPET:-

```
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(finalUrl);

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

I checked CloseableHttpResponse and HttpEntity but none of them is providing method to parse multipart request.

EDIT 1:
This is my sample response I am receiving at client side stream:-

```
--bvRi5oZum37DUldtLgQGSbc5RRVZxKpjZMO4SYDe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="numeric"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
01010110
--bvRi5oZum37DUldtLgQGSbc5RRVZxKpjZMO4SYDe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="stringmessage"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit
testmessage
--bvRi5oZum37DUldtLgQGSbc5RRVZxKpjZMO4SYDe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="binarydata"; filename="file1"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
HI, THIS IS MY BINARY DATA
--bvRi5oZum37DUldtLgQGSbc5RRVZxKpjZMO4SYDe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ending"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
ending
--bvRi5oZum37DUldtLgQGSbc5RRVZxKpjZMO4SYDe--
```

Comment: I believe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337056/convenient-way-to-parse-incoming-multipart-form-data-parameters-in-a-servlet

Comment: @Boschi Fileupload API methods accept HTTPServletRequest which is not possible in my case as it's a response from the servlet. Please let me know if I am missing some point here.

Comment: I have added a sample message response received at client..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have finally got a workaround for it.

I will be using javax mail MimeMultipart.

Below is a code snipped for the solution:-

```
    ByteArrayDataSource datasource = new ByteArrayDataSource(in, "multipart/form-data");
    MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(datasource);

    int count = multipart.getCount();
    log.debug("count " + count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
        if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
            log.info("text/plain " + bodyPart.getContentType());
            processTextData(bodyPart.getContent());
        } else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("application/octet-stream")) {
            log.info("application/octet-stream " + bodyPart.getContentType());
            processBinaryData(bodyPart.getInputStream()));
        } else {
            log.warn("default " + bodyPart.getContentType());
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if anybody else have any standard solution.

Comment: You are a genius man. I was looking for this for 3 days. Its sad to see java has no standard in their Apache libraries for reading multi-part data or that jaxrs has no standard either. this was simple to use and only took three jars.

Comment: @yfdgvfasdasdas Thanks for your kind words :)

Comment: it is not working when i try to parse the lambda response of multipart/form-data..  :(Is there anyother alternative to it

Comment: @AkS I tried it with sending a JSON as string and 2 pdf and it worked fine here..

Comment: @LeiYang, Which classes are you talking about. I was not using com.sun.xml package anywhere...

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

1. If you know what [`HttpMessageConverters`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) are, then skip the "In General" part.
2. If your client is reactive, than you most likely don't have a big problem. Go to the part named "Reactive Client (Spring Webflux)" for details.
3. If your client is non-reactive i.e. you're using Spring MVC and `RestTemplate` then the last section is for you. In short, it is not possible out of the box and you need to write custom code.

---

### In General

When we want to read multipart data, then we are at the serialization/marshalling layer of our application. This is basically the same layer as when we transform a JSON or an XML document to a POJO via [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for example. What I want to emphasize here is that the logic for parsing multipart data should not take place in a service but rather much earlier.

Our hook to transform multipart data comes as early, as to when an HTTP response enters our application in form of an [`HttpInputMessage`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpInputMessage.html). Out of the box, Spring provides a set of [`HttpMessageConverters`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html), that are able to transform our HTTP response to an object with which we can work. For example, the [MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) is used to read and write all request/responses that have the MediaType "application/Json".

If the application is reactive, then Spring uses [`HttpMessageReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/HttpMessageReader.html)
and [`HttpMessageWriter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/HttpMessageWriter.html) instead of [`HttpMessageConverters`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html). They save the same purpose.

The following two sections show how to read (download) a multipart response via the two different paradigms.

### Reactive Client (Spring Webflux)

This would be the easiest use case and the only thing we need, is already available in [Spring Webflux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/webflux.html) out of the box.

The class [`MultipartHttpMessageReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/multipart/MultipartHttpMessageReader.html) would be doing all the heavy lifting. **In case** it does not behave exactly how you need it to, you can easily extend it and overwrite the methods to your liking. Your custom Reader can then be registered as a bean like so:

```java
@Configuration
public class MultipartMessageConverterConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public CodecCustomizer myCustomMultipartHttpMessageWriter() {
      return configurer -> configurer.customCodecs()
                                     .register(new MyCustomMultipartHttpMessageWriter());
    }
}
```

### Non-Reactive Client (Spring MVC/RestTemplate)

If you have a "classic" application that uses `RestTemplate` to communicate via HTTP, then you need to rely on the aforementioned [`HttpMessageConverters`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html). Unfortunately, the MessageConverter that is responsible for reading multipart data, does not support reading/downloading data:

> Implementation of HttpMessageConverter to read and write 'normal' HTML forms and also to write **(but not read)** multipart data (e.g. file uploads)

Source: [`FormHttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html) Documentation

So what we need to do, is write our own `MessageConverter`, which is able to download multipart data. An easy way to do that, would be to make use of the [`DefaultPartHttpMessageReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/multipart/DefaultPartHttpMessageReader.html) that is internally used by [`MultipartHttpMessageReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/multipart/MultipartHttpMessageReader.html). We don't even need Webflux for that, as it is already shipped with spring-web.

First let us define 2 classes in which we save the several parts the we read:

```java
public class MyCustomPart  {

    public MyCustomPart(byte[] content, String filename, MediaType contentType) {
        //assign to corresponding member variables; here omitted
    }
}

/**
 * Basically a container for a list of objects of the class above.
 */
public class MyCustomMultiParts {
    public MyCustomMultiParts(List<MyCustomPart> parts){
        //assign to corresponding member variable; here omitted
    }
}
```

Later on, you can always take each Part and convert it to whatever is appropriate. The `MyCustomPart` represents a single block of your multipart data response. The `MyCustomMultiParts` represent the whole multipart data.

Now we come to the meaty stuff:

```java
public class CustomMultipartHttpMessageConverter implements HttpMessageConverter<MyCustomMultiParts> {
  
    private final List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();

    private final DefaultPartHttpMessageReader defaultPartHttpMessageReader;

    public CustomMultipartHttpMessageConverter() {
        this.supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        this.defaultPartHttpMessageReader = new DefaultPartHttpMessageReader();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(final Class<?> clazz, @Nullable final MediaType mediaType) {
        if (!MyCustomMultiParts.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) { 
            return false;
        }
        if (mediaType == null) {
            return true;
        }
        for (final MediaType supportedMediaType : getSupportedMediaTypes()) {
            if (supportedMediaType.includes(mediaType) && mediaType.getParameter("boundary") != null) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * This wraps the input message into a "reactive" input message, that the reactive DefaultPartHttpMessageReader uses.
     */
    private ReactiveHttpInputMessage wrapHttpInputMessage(final HttpInputMessage message) {
        return new ReactiveHttpInputMessage() {
            @Override
            public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
                return message.getHeaders();
            }

            @SneakyThrows //Part of lombok. Just use a try catch block if you're not using it
            @Override
            public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
                final DefaultDataBuffer wrappedBody = new DefaultDataBufferFactory()
                        .wrap(message.getBody().readAllBytes());
                return Flux.just(wrappedBody);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public MyCustomMultiParts read(@Nullable final Class<? extends MyCustomMultiParts> clazz,
                                           final HttpInputMessage message) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        final ReactiveHttpInputMessage wrappedMessage = wrapHttpInputMessage(message);
        final ResolvableType resolvableType = ResolvableType.forClass(byte[].class); //plays no role
        List<Part> rawParts = defaultPartHttpMessageReader.read(resolvableType, wrappedMessage, Map.of())//
                .buffer()//
                .blockFirst();
        //You can check here whether the result exists or just continue
        final List<MyCustomPart> customParts = rawParts.stream()// Now we convert to our customPart
                .map(part -> {
                    //Part consists of a DataBuffer, we make a byte[] so we can convert it to whatever we want later
                    final byte[] content = Optional.ofNullable(part.content().blockFirst())//
                            .map(DataBuffer::asByteBuffer)//
                            .map(ByteBuffer::array)//
                            .orElse(new byte[]{});

                    final HttpHeaders headers = part.headers();
                    final String filename = headers.getContentDisposition().getFilename();
                    final MediaType contentType = headers.getContentType();
                    return new MyCustomPart(content, filename, contentType);
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new MyCustomMultiParts(customParts);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final MyCustomMultiParts parts, final MediaType contentType,
                      final HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) {
        // we're just interested in reading
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(final Class<?> clazz, final MediaType mediaType) {
        // we're just interested in reading
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
        return this.supportedMediaTypes;
    }
}
```

From here on, you should know better what to do with your "CustomPart". Whether it is a JSON, a bitmap or a PDF. From the byte array you can convert it into anything.

Now if you want to test it, you only have to add your CustomConverter to a `RestTemplate` and then "await" the `MyCustomMultiParts` that we defined:

```java
// This could also be inside your @Bean definition of RestTemplate of course
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
messageConverters.add(new CustomMultipartHttpMessageConverter());

String url = "http://server.of.choice:8080/whatever-endpoint-that-sends-multiparts/";
final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(List.of(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));
final HttpEntity<Void> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
//here we await our MyCustomMultiParts
final MyCustomMultiParts entity = restTemplate.exchange(url, GET, requestEntity, MyCustomMultiParts.class);
```

Comment: This is a very interesting answer, but it is Spring Framework specific, whereas the question makes no mention of spring. An answer for this question should stick to Apache HTTP Client's api.

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I do see it. Welp, guess I'll still leave it, if it isn't too off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Mime4j from Apache is one way to parse the responses from client-side. Its a common practice to  use a tool like this.

You can refer this link - http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.james.mime4j.MimeException

You can download the jar from this link -
http://james.apache.org/download.cgi#Apache_Mime4J

Comment: I tried with it but it's not able to parse the stream. Most probably because it's expecting in different way. I have added a sample message response received at client